# Dont find MYSQL in flask with WSGI

Tags: python, flask, deployment, apache2, wsgi

Errormessage when i try to enter my application, deployed on APACHE2
What is wrong here?
This is the guide i followed: https://codeshack.io/login-system-python-flask-mysql/

```
import sys
if sys.version_info[0]<3:
 raise Exception("Python3 required! Current (wrong) version: '%s'" % sys.version_info)
sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/html/pythonlogin/')
from main import app as application
```

Error here:

```
Fri Mar 26 21:38:36.632202 2021] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 7865] AH00163: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.1.1f mod_wsgi/4.6.8 Python/3.8 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Mar 26 21:38:36.632287 2021] [core:notice] [pid 7865] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Fri Mar 26 21:38:45.326718 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 7868] [client 162.158.183.139:37968] mod_wsgi (pid=7868): Failed to exec Python script file '/var/www/html/pythonlogin/appen.wsgi'.
[Fri Mar 26 21:38:45.326851 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 7868] [client 162.158.183.139:37968] mod_wsgi (pid=7868): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/html/pythonlogin/appen.wsgi'.
[Fri Mar 26 21:38:45.327350 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 7868] [client 162.158.183.139:37968] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Fri Mar 26 21:38:45.327391 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 7868] [client 162.158.183.139:37968]   File "/var/www/html/pythonlogin/appen.wsgi", line 5, in <module>
[Fri Mar 26 21:38:45.327400 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 7868] [client 162.158.183.139:37968]     from main import app as application
[Fri Mar 26 21:38:45.327412 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 7868] [client 162.158.183.139:37968]   File "/var/www/html/pythonlogin/main.py", line 2, in <module>
[Fri Mar 26 21:38:45.327418 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 7868] [client 162.158.183.139:37968]     from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
[Fri Mar 26 21:38:45.327443 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 7868] [client 162.158.183.139:37968] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_mysqldb'
```

Comment: the last error says: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_mysqldb', which means you don't have that module installed

Comment: Yes, since it works when i -not- deploy it i must have it?

Comment: You can see the mann.py here https://codeshack.io/login-system-python-flask-mysql/ this is the guide i have used

Comment: And mine i said, when i use run flask i can enter the adress at ip.ip.ip.ip:5000/pythonlogin

Comment: if the code imports it, you must have it, which is your case

Comment: It must be in the main, in the wsgi-file or what? Since i can run it, and use it - i must have the mysql module.

Comment: you need to have it installed. installation instructions differ, but usually it goes like `pip install flask-mysqldb` that needs to be run on the console. sometimes it gets installed via a requirements file. How  did you start your project. Is it a template? tutorial?

Comment: This is not a venv and like i said to you, this is working while i just run flask - it is just  when it is deployed it don’t work. So i have it installed

Comment: pip install is not only for venv, anyway what mechanism do you use to deploy?

Comment: I use apache and wsgi

Comment: And i know that is not just for venv, but I just thought it was good to tell everything. Since it works when i run it as production all of the modules must ber there?